# Triggering Logic Apps Workflow from Azure Data Factory using Managed Identity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps, azure-managed-identity

For a project I am working on, we need to trigger a Logic App workflow from Azure Data Factory.

We were thinking to do the integration/authentication in a secure way by using Managed Identity and hence avoiding the use of any client secrets.

Practically, we have a Web activity in ADF which needs to call the Logic App workflow endpoint (in a secure way) avoiding the SAS values in the url or using any client secrets in body.

Has anyone had any experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you are looking for:

[image: Azure data Factory UI]

And here is the detailed REST API URL to trigger it. Keep in mind this method requires you to give your ADF RBAC to whatever Logic App you are wanting ADF to trigger.

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{YourSubscriptionID}/resourceGroups/{YourResourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/{YourLogicAppName}/triggers/Manual/run?api-version=2016-06-01
```

I tested this using a Simple SendGrid Email test and it worked.

If you for some reason don't like this method, you could also have ADF drop a Message Queue into Azure Storage, then have your Logic App listening to that Storage Queue and trigger when a new message is received. In that case ADF and the logic app just need access to the same Queue, and not directly to each other.

Comment: This is indeed what we were looking for! Thank you!